# Error generating JWT key using Google Cloud Platform MQTT

Tags: google-cloud-platform, jwt, mqtt, iot

Using these instructions from Google Cloud Platform IOT Core website https://cloud.google.com/iot/docs/how-tos/credentials/jwts#iot-core-jwt-java run generates this error:

> java.security.spec.InvalidKeySpecException: 
>   java.security.InvalidKeyException: invalid key format

The method used:

```
createJwtRsa(String projectId, String privateKeyFile)
```

The "privateKeyFile" parm is coded: to the file: rsa_private.pem like:

```
private static final String PRIVATE_KEY_FILE_PATH = "/Volumes/Code/mqtt/nodejs-docs-samples/iot/mqtt_example/rsa_private.pem";
```

The key was generated following these instructions:
https://cloud.google.com/iot/docs/quickstart

Any help to understand how to fix this error would be appreciated.

Comment: Using this library: io.jsonwebtoken.impl.crypto;

Answer (score 1):

I had to covert the key using method at the bottom of this page: https://cloud.google.com/iot/docs/how-tos/credentials/keys

```
openssl pkcs8 -topk8 -inform PEM -outform DER -in rsa_private.pem \
-nocrypt > rsa_private_pkcs8
```

This fixed the issue.